# How to use Firebase firestore with AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I use and learn about using Firebase Firestore with AngularDart

Answer (score 3):

We have an open issue tracking support in the official repository.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-dart/issues/131

Subscribe for updates!